# Invariance of binary black hole gravitational waves

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, binary-stars

Why BBH gravitational waves can be parameterized with the mass ratio? (and is not necessary the value of the two masses explicitly)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: They are parameterised by the chirp mass, not the mass ratio. Perhaps you could explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Einstein equations are scale invariant, there is no intrinsic length scale set by the theory itself. As a consequence, all solutions to the (vacuum) Einstein equations have an overall scale invariance. You can rescale the solution by an overall factor and still get a solution.

In particular, this is true for a black hole binary and the gravitational waves it produces. If you take one solution for a black hole binary, you can get another one by rescaling the entire solution by a constant factor. In this new solution all component masses also get rescaled by this factor. The mass ratio on the other hand is invariant under this rescaling.

One way of using this invariance, is to give all dimensionful quantities in the binary (the mass, separation, frequency etc.) relative to one intrinsic scale of the binary, usually the total mass. In the "geometric" units the total mass will not feature anywhere in the solution (but the mass ratio will). If you then need a solution with a particular total mass, it is just a matter of converting the right units.